# Why do I have to divide the origin of a quad by 4 instead of 2?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm currently transitioning from C#/XNA to C#/OpenTK but I'm getting stuck at the basics.

So I have this Sprite-Class:

```
public static bool EnableDebugDraw = true;
public float X;
public float Y;

public float OriginX = 0;
public float OriginY = 0;

public float Width = 0.1f;
public float Height = 0.1f;

public Color TintColor = Color.Red;
float _layerDepth = 0f;

public void Render()
    {
        Vector2[] corners =
        {
            new Vector2(X-OriginX,Y-OriginY), //top left
            new Vector2(X +Width -OriginX,Y-OriginY),//top right
            new Vector2(X +Width-OriginX,Y+Height-OriginY),//bottom rigth
            new Vector2(X-OriginX,Y+Height-OriginY)//bottom left
        };
        GL.Color3(TintColor);
        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) GL.Vertex3(corners[i].X,corners[i].Y,_layerDepth);                             
        }
        GL.End();

        if (EnableDebugDraw)
        {
            GL.Color3(Color.Violet);
            GL.PointSize(3);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Points);
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) GL.Vertex2(corners[i]);
            }
            GL.End();

            GL.Color3(Color.Green);
            GL.Begin(BeginMode.Points);
            GL.Vertex2(X + OriginX, Y + OriginY);
            GL.End();
        }
```

With the following setup I try to set the origin of the quad to the middle of the quad.

```
_sprite.OriginX = _sprite.Width / 2;
_sprite.OriginY = _sprite.Height / 2;
```

but this sets the origin to the upper right corner of the quad, so i have to

```
_sprite.OriginX = _sprite.Width / 4;
_sprite.OriginY = _sprite.Height / 4;
```

However this is not the intended behaviour, could you advise me how I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you declare your corners as such:

```
    Vector2[] corners =
    {
        new Vector2(X-OriginX,Y-OriginY), //top left
        new Vector2(X +Width -OriginX,Y-OriginY),//top right
        new Vector2(X +Width-OriginX,Y+Height-OriginY),//bottom rigth
        new Vector2(X-OriginX,Y+Height-OriginY)//bottom left
    };
```

It seems that you are adjusting the corners to be around X and Y and are treating (X, Y) as your origin and your OriginX and OriginY values are just the offsets.

That being said, I don't think this line within your EnableDebugDraw block is right, assuming this is your attempt at drawing the origin:

```
        GL.Vertex2(X + OriginX, Y + OriginY);
```

I believe your origin should simply be (X, Y) making your draw statement:

```
        GL.Vertex2(X, Y);
```

Comment: thanks, now I feel really dumb :D, would upvote if I had the reputation

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes. :)